# Accelerated charged particles produce electromagnetic radiation, but holes (the charge carriers) do not. Is this correct?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Holes are treated as particles in solid-state physics, so I've had some trouble with reasoning through this properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holes, if accelerated, also radiate because the Maxwell equations contain any charge as a field source.

Comment: this is true from a certain perspective, but really it would be the electrons emitting the radiation, not the holes

Comment: @DanII: We can take a piece of matter with only one hole (a dust particle) and accelerate it in a strong electric and/or varying magnetic field. The piece will radiate because it is charged positively. All constituent charges are involved in the process, but we may say that it is the hole who radiates since there is no nucleus or electron with a positive charge $+|e|$. By the way, radiation of an accelerated proton is, in some sense, the hole radiation of Hydrogen atom ;-) (similarly, radiation of any positive ion too).

Comment: @DanII: If you mean a recombination radiation, it is kind of a dipole radiation.

Comment: I've considered both of those possibilities. I've essentially tried to imagine the electrons' EM fields as summing in a way that makes it seem that the hole is producing the fields, but with the Poynting vector in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Angel: Maxwell's equation's are linear so the points of view are equivalent. This is no different from the freshman physics trick of treating a mass with a hole as a mass with a hole superimposed on a negative mass.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses. The question seemed tricky before, but now I have good places from which to start imagining the situation.